# Styling all ListItems in an app, even those in a templated control

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, coding-style, custom-controls

I've create a style for ListItems that I want to use across all ListBoxes in my application. I can set these manually like so:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="">
```

But I'm having trouble getting the style to apply to every single ListBox in my application without touching each one and adding the above attribute.

In addition, and more importantly, I want to apply the style to list boxes used within custom templated controls. Right now I have to modify the Generic.xaml theme in the control library... not something i think I should have to do.

Fairly certain this has something to do with themes, btu having a heck of a time figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use implicit styles.
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implicit-Styles-in-Silverlight-4.aspx
You define one global style for a type (in your case ListBoxItem) and then this style is the new default style for your app.

If you need any further information, just leave a comment.

BR,

TJ

Comment: Seriously? I was hunting all that time and all I had to do was remove my Key from the style? GRRRR.... Thanks TJ, that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [implicit styles](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implicit-Styles-in-Silverlight-4.aspx) in Silverlight 4.

Define your style in the regular way:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    ....
<Style>
```

then create the implicit style:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListBoxStyle}" />
```

Comment: This is the better pattern for implicit styles. This way you can create additional custom styles that are based on the default style. If you just create a single style with no key, there is no way to do that.